# javascript optimize .map to spread operator

Tags: javascript

I am using a recursive function to make async calls if there is an odata nextlink. It works fine as it is by using map to push the items into teamsArray. The problem hover is that I am looping through each item instead of merging the objects together. I tried to use the following but with no avail:

```
teamsArray = {}
    teamsArray = { ...teamsArray, ...latstestResults}
```

Current code that does work but is not optimized:

```
export const fetchAllTeams = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchAllTeamsRequest());
    };
};

export const fetchAllTeamsRequest = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(getAllTeamStarted());

        let teamsArray = [];
        getAllTeams("", teamsArray, dispatch);
    };
};

const getAllTeams = (url, teamsArray, dispatch) => {
    if (url === "") {
        url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf?$top=10";
    }

    const getTeams = adalGraphFetch(fetch, url, {})
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status != 200 && response.status != 204) {
                dispatch(fetchAllTeamsFailure("fout"));
                return;
            }
            response.json().then(result => {
                if (result["@odata.nextLink"]) {
                    const teams = objectToArray(result.value);
                    teams.map(team => {
                        teamsArray.push(team);
                    });
                    getAllTeams(result["@odata.nextLink"], teamsArray, dispatch);
                } else {
                    const latestResult = objectToArray(result.value);
                    latestResult.map(team => {
                        teamsArray.push(team);
                    });
                    console.log("the teams", teamsArray);
                    dispatch(fetchAllTeamsSucces(result));
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchAllTeamsFailure(error));
        });
};
```

Comment: It's not an array if it's an object (`{}`)... Is the point fetching all teams until there is no `nextLink`?

Comment: `teamsArray.push(...latestResult)`

Comment: yes I am currently using an array in my solution. Changed it to an object, because I wanted to use the spread operator instead of looping the results. The point is indeed to fetch all teams until there is no nextlink.

Comment: @adiga, that worked indeed. Guess I was mixing it up by assigning the teamsArray to an object. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you.

I refactored the paged fetching into an `async` function that calls itself if there are more items to fetch, then eventually resolves with the full array of results.

Dry-coded, so there may be bugs and YMMV, but hope it helps.

```
export const fetchAllTeams = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchAllTeamsRequest());
  };
};

export const fetchAllTeamsRequest = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(getAllTeamStarted());
    try {
      const teamsArray = await getPaged(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf?$top=10",
      );
      dispatch(fetchAllTeamsSucces(teamsArray));
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(fetchAllTeamsFailure(err));
    }
  };
};

const getPaged = async (url, resultArray = []) => {
  const response = await adalGraphFetch(fetch, url, {});
  if (response.status != 200 && response.status != 204) {
    throw new Error("failed to fetch teams");
  }
  const result = await response.json();
  objectToArray(result.value).forEach(team => resultArray.push(team));
  if (result["@odata.nextLink"]) {
    // Get more items...
    return getPaged(resultArray, result["@odata.nextLink"]);
  }
  return resultArray; // All done, return the teams array.
};
```